# Which language do you recommend to learn after php? (2016)

Tags: programming-languages

I'm know php, i can use laravel and yii, yii2 frameworks, i can make a plugins for wordpress, modules for prestashop.

I want to learn a new language. The new programming language is must be work in linux servers. it must be have understandable documentation. It's better if have short syntax and support mobile platform.

I just want to ask: for senior php developer wich language is better to learn.

Please share your experience.

Thank You.

Comment: [Go](http://golang.org).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

even I was in the same situation as you.. after few days of research, I concluded with nodejs being the best option.. quite new but promising.. and fits in all requirements you mentioned..